# Code Signing Certificate Java

Tags: java, ssl, applet

Let me get this out in the open first, i barely know what Code Signing Certificate does but i know i need it because i want to post my java applet game on a website and have a less scary warning sign. but i have three main questions

https://www.startssl.com/?app=40

would startSSL™ Identity Verified work so i get a less scary warning sign to users.

and how hard / what do you need to do to the applet to add the Signing Certificate to it ?

and for $60 is that for unlimited applets ?

Answer (score 0):

Startssl certificates does not work automatically.  This is not a installed trustcenter for java. There is an open issue for oracle to include it. But this issue has its age.

https://forum.startcom.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1815

You need to add the trustcenter in every client installation which would be a no go for applets. I know the price of startssls certificate is interesting. But go to bigger trustcenter to avoid problems.

With a signed applet you will get a more friendly info message that a signed applet would be run. By the way in newer Java versions unsigned applets are completely blocked.

A code certificate can be used with as much code as you like but certificates could have a valid time range of eg 2 years.

For code signing there are a lot of tutorials available, eg using maven there are signing plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, always appreciated. The main reason i want it is to make the warning sign less threatening looking. I may pick to choose this company http://codesigning.ksoftware.net/ , they have good reviews and on there website talks about, java applets. they are the cheapest i found at $95 per year, which is a lot more than i was hoping. But if i use ksoftware at least it will work. Quick question    do you know any cheaper ones or better companies for around the same price? But anyway Thanks for the help.

Comment: For this price I could give you no advice. But there are combination certificates with SSL and website certification. May be you could get a better price with that. But only for codesigning I have no better idea.